# javascript ajax post form function and validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my code so far:

```
$(function () {
    $('.contact-form').submit(function (event) {
        $(this).find("input , textarea").each(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == "") {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("label, p").addClass("error");
                input.addClass("error").one("keydown", function () {
                    $("label").removeClass("error");
                    self.removeClass("error");
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**What it does:** 
It prevents the form from redirecting to the php script, it turns all fields red (the error class) if they are not filled, and gives the labels an error class.

**What I need help with:** 
Fix so if one field is getting filled remove the error class as it doesn't right now.

Fix so that the label error class gets removed on the specific field when filled (right now it removes the class on all labels over all fields)

And run this code when every field / textarea is validated to be filled:

```
var form = $(this);
$.ajax({
    type: form.attr('method'),
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize()
}).done(function () {
    // Optionally alert the user of success here...
    console.log("jag lyckades!");
}).fail(function () {
    // Optionally alert the user of an error here...
    console.log("jag lyckades INTE");
});
event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
```

**My html:**

```
<form class="contact-form" action="<?= path(" postform.php "); ?>" method="post" validate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="firstname">Förnamn*</label>
            <input type="text" class="required" name="firstname" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="lastname">Efternamn</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="email">E-post*</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="number">Telefon*</label>
            <input type="text" name="number" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <label for="message">Meddelande*</label>
            <textarea name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p>Fält markerade med * är obligatoriska</p>
            <input class="btn-form" type="submit" value="Skicka">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks... I really appreciate your time guys

EDIT:
This is my code at the moment:
http://jsfiddle.net/dmyhd90d/

My problems now:
Having the ajax call run when there's no more form errors ( it runs even if none is filled now )

The label error class is getting the error class removed now instantly when you fill the fields, but the fields stay error classed till I hit the send button, then it revalidates.

Comment: Can you add `$('.error').removeClass("error")` right after `$('.contact-form').submit(function (event) {` ? It's easier to start by clearing all errors, then revalidate any errors that still exist. Easier to keep track of.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Now my fields gets the class error removed. 

What's left: 
Somehow relate the labels to the fields so the error class of the labels gets removed aswell

Run the ajax code when all is validated correct

Comment: `on("keydown", function () {
                    $("label [for='" + $(this).attr('name') + +"']").removeClass("error");
                    self.removeClass("error");
                });` and one should be on ?

Comment: I read that "one" does what "on" does but just once. 

Where should I put 

on("keydown", function () { $("label [for='" + $(this).attr('name') + +"']").removeClass("error"); self.removeClass("error"); });

?
I really appreciate your time

Comment: $(function() {
  $('.contact-form').submit(function(event) {
  $('.error').removeClass("error");
  
 $(this).find("input , textarea").each(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == "") {
   event.preventDefault();
   $("label, p").addClass("error");
   input.addClass("error").on("keydown", function () { $("label [for='" + $(this).attr('name') + +"']").removeClass("error"); self.removeClass("error"); });
  }
 });

  });
});

Comment: That codes removes the class on the fields but labels still stays errored ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets post it all in one place because comments are not the place for this anymore

First:
with form submissions, you can often let the error field just clear when you re-validate so by adding

```
$('.contact-form').submit(function (event) {
    $('.error').removeClass("error"); // This
```

you can clear the errors out and re-validate the whole form from scratch.

second, you're trying to bind an event so that when you edit the input it clear the error from that input and it's label but right  now you're clearing all labels errors so you can change it like this

```
 if (input.val() == "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("label, p").addClass("error");
            input.addClass("error").one("keydown", function () {
                // $("label").removeClass("error");
                $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']").removeClass("error"); // becomes this
                self.removeClass("error");
            });
        }
```

To associate the input you're looking at, with it's label. BTW just so you know it's good to put input id="something" and label for="something" as that'll link the label to the input in html, when you click the label. Remember to keep your names for submitting though.

Additionally I think that

```
 $("label, p").addClass("error");
```

will add an error to all your labels at once. You might want to change it also to add errors only to the fields that have errors

```
$("label[for='" + $(this).attr('name') + "'], p").addClass("error");
```

Edit to answer the comment

```
 $('.contact-form').submit(function (event) {
    $('.error').removeClass("error"); // This
    $(this).find("input , textarea").each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('name') + "'], p").addClass("error"); 
            input.addClass("error").one("keydown", function () {
                $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']").removeClass("error");
                self.removeClass("error");
            });
        }
    });
    if ($(".errors").length <= 0) { // If there are no more error classes
        // Do $.ajax() here
        // http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ <- you need to read this and other similar SO posts about ajax
    }
});
```

Comment: I did exactly as you wrote but the labels isn't working. http://gyazo.com/b2664724fb16e71346ce900a6b2a344e

It just keeps the class error

Have I missed something?

Comment: hmm sorry it's early morning here and my brain isn't working any better. Can you try `console.log($(this));` after trying to remove the label and see what sort of properties you see in the debug console (f12 on many browsers)? Does it show the correct element? does it have a name? I'll try it when I get to work.

Comment: THANKS. $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('name') + '"], p").addClass("error"); 
Worked!

Now, sorry to bother you... How do I start the ajax if there's no errors left?

Comment: Unfortunately the ajax runs even if it has errors with that code. Missed something again? hehe *giggle*

Comment: And by errors I don't mean code errors, I mean input errors.

Comment: Updated the firstpost with my current code at the far bottom.